# Android AdMob Banner doesnt work

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, ads

Im trying to put ads on my app, but for some reason the Ad banner doesnt work, which is wired because the Interstitial Ad do work.

here is my xml :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fartDisplay"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="My-Ad-Unit-Id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and here is my java code:

```
private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fart);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
```

im also getting this on the logcat:

```
09-04 19:34:54.919: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2841): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-04 19:34:54.929: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2841): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the below in build.gradle file inside dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

Also you have to add the below in manifest.xml file

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Another issue i see here is in ads:adUnitId="My-Ad-Unit-Id"
You have to add your ad unit id in strings.xml file and put the string value in the tag as below:
    ads:adUnitId="@string/My-Ad-Unit-Id"

Comment: i have the meta-data, and i changed the unit-id to the string so it wont be visible, and im using eclipse, gradle is only at android studio no?

Comment: Follow these steps for Eclipse IDE https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start